# VBA macro - extract time from date & time excel cell - VBA

Tags: excel, date, time, vba

I have to columns B and C which are containing data under the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` - which represents the start (column B) and the end dates (column C) of some meetings.

I'm trying to create a VBA macro that can extract from both of the columns only the time under the format `hh:mm` and then calculate the difference between the two timings in order to find out the duration of each meeting (the result will be displayed on column D).

Can you please advised what can be done into here?

Comment: If B/C are datetimes just pass them both as they are as arguments to datediff()

Comment: will the date part always be the same for each pair ??

Comment: this does not need a macro, can be calculated with formulas

Comment: Yes,the data contained from both columns are having the same date part.

Comment: @avb it has to be in a macro as the data for these meetings is extracted from outlook's calendar

Answer (score 2):

In column D use the formula

```
=(C:C-B:B)*24
```

to get the difference in hours.

---

Or instead just use the below formula in column D

```
=C:C-B:B
```

and format column D as time to get the difference in a format like `hh:mm`

---

you can add this formula to a desired range with VBA if necessary like

```
With Worksheets("MySheet").Range("D1:D5").Formula = "=(C:C-B:B)*24"
```

or time formatted like

```
With Worksheets("MySheet").Range("D1:D5")
    .Formula = "=C:C-B:B"
    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub difff()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "D") = Cells(i, "C") - Cells(i, "B")
    Next i

    Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `19/06/2017  13:30:00` in `A1` and `20/06/2017  13:39:00` in `A2`.
The formula `=A2-A1` given the custom number format of `[h]:mm:ss` returns `24:09:00`.
The square brackets around the `h` tell Excel to show times over 24 hours.
  Without the square brackets it will show the time as `00:09:00`.  This is because it is calculating as 1 day and 9 minutes, but is not showing the count of days.

To get just the time from a date you can either just format as a time which will keep the dart part of your date/time but display just the time.
Or, you can remove the integer of the date/time to get just the time - the date part will show as 00/01/1900 in this case.  `=A1-INT(A1)`